# Hide an Element inside of an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to hide a header inside of an iframe, but for some reason, it is not working. Can someone look at my code and help me figure out why the header is still visible? Thanks.

```html
<iframe id="booking_iframe" src="https://bananahostels.com/booking-engine/cacao-hostel" width="100%" height="1500px" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

```js
$('#booking_iframe').load(function() {
  $('#booking_iframe').contents().find('.hostel-branding').hide();
}
```

Comment: It's not possible in this case as the content of the iframe is on a different domain to the parent page

Answer (score 0):

Measure the height of the header using the tools provided in FF developer edition, Chrome probably has a similar function.

Namely right click > inspect element > small ruler icon in the top right.
then wrap your Iframe inside of another div which has `overflow:hidden;` specified in your css, Then all you need to do is on the Iframe set your Css value `transform:translateX(-theHeightOftheHeader.);`

Maybe a bit hacky, but since this is an external URL that would seem to be your best option.